# Other Side of an Einstein Rosen Bridge

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, wormholes, multiverse

We get an ERB when we replace $u^2$ by $r - 2M$ in Schwartzchild Metric, therefore the metric becomes symmetric along the horizon $(r = 2M)$. Why should it mean that crossing the horizon leads you to another universe? Why not just the other side of the same black hole, or even you simply trace your way back home? What part of the ERB metric makes us think that it leads to another universe?

Answer (score 0):

$r$ is greater than $0$. When it is greater than one, we are outside the horizon of the black hole. When it is between zero and one, we are between the singularity and the horizon.

That is all (in our universe), but represents regions $1$ and $2$ respectively of the ER diagram. Regions $3$ and $4$ are speculative 'out of our universe' places.